# Android Spinners

Tags: android

I am working on my first ever android app, and I'm creating basic exercise/calorie counter. I have two spinners, one for the selected type of exercise, and one for the time spent preforming said exercise in minutes. I need to be able to check the value/position of both spinners so I can do something like this:

**PSUEDO CODE:**

```
if(Exercise spinner = "push-ups")
{
     CaloriesBurned = TimeSpinnerValue*450
}
if(Exercise spinner = "sit-up")
{
   CaloriesBurned = TimeSpinnerValue*350
}
```

etc . . . nothing fancy. My spinners are populated from a String Array in my String.xml. But I dont know how get the value of the spinner so I can use it in some IF statements in my java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this for compair any string with your spinner.

```
spinner.equals("push-ups");
```

Comment: How do I call/create the spinner object I made in my XML file, in my java code? So that I can do something like you are suggesting?

Comment: you can create object of spinner in this way.
`Spinner spin = new Spinner(yourClass.this);`
and an another way in if you already define Spinner in your xml file then you can use something like..
`Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);`

Answer (score 2):

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    String selectedString = (String) (yourSpinner.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}});
```

[check this link fro more info](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [`OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) for getting the selected value from the Spinner. Then override,

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {

         int id = parent.getId();
            switch (id) {
        case R.id.first_spinner:
            // your stuff here
            break;

        case R.id.second_spinner:
            // your stuff here
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generically, you'll want to follow this pattern:

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = Spinner.getAdapter();
int position = Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
Object value = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Since you are loading it with String values, you can then cast value to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Have some field in your activity to hold value of spinner, initialize with some defaultvalue
implement onItemSelectedListener on spinners, and in onItemSelected get value of selected item, by position argument of `onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id)`